# No confirmation dialog when flagging in Review

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

I've accidently flagged an answer in [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review), because there's no confirmation dialog. That should be fixed to prevent accident flagging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is that in general you want to flag stuff when you are there, we already suppress the flagging dialog for high scoring questions. I do not want to add friction to the process.

Accidents happen, if you flagged it by mistake mods will simply ignore it.

Comment: But how will they know it was a mistake?