# Unflagging reviewed first-answers

Tags: feature-request, support, flags

OK, this might sound down-right dumb to some people, others way see it as a user issue - I don't know, I'm just here to bring it up...

While using the review page to moderate first answers I was curious as to how I mark something as being 'OK' - selecting the `flag` option from the `full answer` obviously gave me the dialog within which I found no obvious method to achieve what I wanted and so left; the next thing I did (stupidly, or not) was to hit the `flag for attention` button, just to see if I got a dialog with options again, but alas - I flagged a reasonable answer by mistake.

I know I should have been more careful, but obviously curious as to how it all works so that I may at least do these things knowledgeably and competently.

I know I won't make this error again, but is it worth thinking of a 'whoops' button of sorts?

Also, as an aside, would it be possible for my action to be manually revoked?

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82137/view-pending-flags

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the benefit of this. The mods will just ignore the misflag. You will lose a little flag weight, but that's not a big deal. See [this related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78877/no-confirmation-dialog-when-flagging-in-review) for a mod's opinion on a similar matter.